# What "install library" in Linux actually means?

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries

I want to compile a project from source file and one of the dependencies is XmlRpc++ library. I found this library, and after big battle managed to compile it in Linux. But there is no "make install" option and I ended with a directory with .o files and one `libXmlRpc.a` file.

But the main project was not able to find this library on configuration process. So, I was forced to use following options on ./configure command:

```
LDFLAGS=-L../xmlrpc++0.7/ CPPFLAGS=-I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/
```

As a result, the header file has been found. But regardless of this success, an error still appears and I don't know what it actually means (what the configuration tool can't find) and what I have to do in order to fix it. Here is the console output:

```
> checking XmlRpc.h usability... yes
> checking XmlRpc.h presence... yes
> checking for XmlRpc.h... yes
> configure: error: Can't find/use -lXmlRpc. Please install XmlRpc++ first.
```

As Ignacio suggested, the config.log file contains following:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by xchm configure 1.23, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-xmlrpc --enable-static LDFLAGS=-L../xmlrpc++0.7/ CPPFLAGS=-I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = SmallBug2
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.2.0-23-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:41:14 UTC 2012

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/lib/libfm
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

; I deleted some lines here because of 30000 char limit... - johnfound

configure:6901: $? = 0
configure:6901: result: yes
configure:6901: checking for memory.h
configure:6901: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6901: $? = 0
configure:6901: result: yes
configure:6901: checking for strings.h
configure:6901: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6901: $? = 0
configure:6901: result: yes
configure:6901: checking for inttypes.h
configure:6901: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6901: $? = 0
configure:6901: result: yes
configure:6901: checking for stdint.h
configure:6901: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6901: $? = 0
configure:6901: result: yes
configure:6901: checking for unistd.h
configure:6901: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6901: $? = 0
configure:6901: result: yes
configure:6913: checking for int32_t
configure:6913: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6913: $? = 0
configure:6913: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:60:22: error: expected expression before ')' token
configure:6913: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (sizeof ((int32_t)))
|           return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6913: result: yes
configure:6924: checking for int16_t
configure:6924: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6924: $? = 0
configure:6924: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:60:22: error: expected expression before ')' token
configure:6924: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (sizeof ((int16_t)))
|           return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6924: result: yes
configure:6935: checking for uint16_t
configure:6935: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6935: $? = 0
configure:6935: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:60:23: error: expected expression before ')' token
configure:6935: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (sizeof ((uint16_t)))
|           return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6935: result: yes
configure:6946: checking for uint32_t
configure:6946: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6946: $? = 0
configure:6946: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:60:23: error: expected expression before ')' token
configure:6946: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (sizeof ((uint32_t)))
|           return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6946: result: yes
configure:6957: checking for uint64_t
configure:6957: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6957: $? = 0
configure:6957: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:60:23: error: expected expression before ')' token
configure:6957: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (sizeof ((uint64_t)))
|           return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6957: result: yes
configure:6969: checking chm_lib.h usability
configure:6969: gcc -c -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c >&5
configure:6969: $? = 0
configure:6969: result: yes
configure:6969: checking chm_lib.h presence
configure:6969: gcc -E -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.c
configure:6969: $? = 0
configure:6969: result: yes
configure:6969: checking for chm_lib.h
configure:6969: result: yes
configure:6977: checking for chm_open in -lchm
configure:7002: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -pthread -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -L../xmlrpc++0.7/ conftest.c -lchm   >&5
configure:7002: $? = 0
configure:7011: result: yes
configure:7039: checking how to run the C++ preprocessor
configure:7066: g++ -E -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.cpp
configure:7066: $? = 0
configure:7080: g++ -E -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.cpp
conftest.cpp:25:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:7080: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_LIBCHM 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:7105: result: g++ -E
configure:7125: g++ -E -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.cpp
configure:7125: $? = 0
configure:7139: g++ -E -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.cpp
conftest.cpp:25:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:7139: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_LIBCHM 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:7170: checking XmlRpc.h usability
configure:7170: g++ -c   -W -Wall -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.cpp >&5
configure:7170: $? = 0
configure:7170: result: yes
configure:7170: checking XmlRpc.h presence
configure:7170: g++ -E -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ conftest.cpp
configure:7170: $? = 0
configure:7170: result: yes
configure:7170: checking for XmlRpc.h
configure:7170: result: yes
configure:7195: g++ -o conftest   -W -Wall -I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -L../xmlrpc++0.7/ conftest.cpp -lchm  -lXmlRpc -lssl >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:7195: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define ENABLE_NLS 1
| #define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
| #define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
| #define PACKAGE "xchm"
| #define VERSION "1.23"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_LIBCHM 1
| #define HAVE_XMLRPC_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include<XmlRpc.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| XmlRpc::XmlRpcServer svr;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:7200: error: Can't find/use -lXmlRpc. Please install XmlRpc++ first.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-L../xmlrpc++0.7/
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_header_XmlRpc_h=yes
ac_cv_header_chm_lib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_lib_chm_chm_open=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_GMSGFMT=/usr/bin/msgfmt
ac_cv_path_GREP=/bin/grep
ac_cv_path_MSGFMT=/usr/bin/msgfmt
ac_cv_path_MSGMERGE=/usr/bin/msgmerge
ac_cv_path_WX_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/bin/wx-config
ac_cv_path_XGETTEXT=/usr/bin/xgettext
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -E'
ac_cv_prog_CXXCPP='g++ -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_type_int16_t=yes
ac_cv_type_int32_t=yes
ac_cv_type_uint16_t=yes
ac_cv_type_uint32_t=yes
ac_cv_type_uint64_t=yes
acl_cv_hardcode_direct=no
acl_cv_hardcode_libdir_flag_spec='${wl}-rpath ${wl}$libdir'
acl_cv_hardcode_libdir_separator=
acl_cv_hardcode_minus_L=no
acl_cv_libext=a
acl_cv_path_LD=/usr/bin/ld
acl_cv_prog_gnu_ld=yes
acl_cv_rpath=done
acl_cv_shlibext=so
acl_cv_wl=-Wl,
am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
am_cv_CXX_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
gt_cv_func_CFLocaleCopyCurrent=no
gt_cv_func_CFPreferencesCopyAppValue=no
gt_cv_func_gnugettext1_libc=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /media/work/asmwork/ProjCHMdocs/xchm-1.23/missing --run aclocal-1.12'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /media/work/asmwork/ProjCHMdocs/xchm-1.23/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /media/work/asmwork/ProjCHMdocs/xchm-1.23/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /media/work/asmwork/ProjCHMdocs/xchm-1.23/missing --run automake-1.12'
AWK='gawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-g -O2 -pthread'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS='-I../xmlrpc++0.7/src/ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__'
CXX='g++'
CXXCPP='g++ -E'
CXXDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CXXFLAGS='  -W -Wall'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
GMSGFMT='/usr/bin/msgfmt'
GREP='/bin/grep'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INTLLIBS=''
INTL_MACOSX_LIBS=''
LDFLAGS='-L../xmlrpc++0.7/'
LIBICONV='-liconv'
LIBINTL=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS='-lchm  -lXmlRpc -lssl'
LINKOPT=''
LTLIBICONV='-liconv'
LTLIBINTL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /media/work/asmwork/ProjCHMdocs/xchm-1.23/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MKINSTALLDIRS='$(top_builddir)/./mkinstalldirs'
MSGFMT='/usr/bin/msgfmt'
MSGMERGE='/usr/bin/msgmerge'
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE='xchm'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='xchm'
PACKAGE_STRING='xchm 1.23'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='xchm'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.23'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POSUB='po'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
USE_NLS='yes'
VERSION='1.23'
WX_CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread'
WX_CFLAGS_ONLY='-pthread'
WX_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/bin/wx-config'
WX_CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__'
WX_CXXFLAGS='-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-2.9 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread'
WX_CXXFLAGS_ONLY=''
WX_LIBS='-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_aui-2.9 -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-2.9 -lwx_gtk3u_html-2.9 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-2.9 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-2.9 -lwx_gtk3u_core-2.9 -lwx_baseu_xml-2.9 -lwx_baseu_net-2.9 -lwx_baseu-2.9 '
WX_LIBS_STATIC=''
WX_RESCOMP=''
WX_VERSION='2.9.5'
WX_VERSION_MAJOR='2'
WX_VERSION_MICRO='5'
WX_VERSION_MINOR='9'
XGETTEXT='/usr/bin/xgettext'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /media/work/asmwork/ProjCHMdocs/xchm-1.23/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "xchm"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xchm"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.23"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "xchm 1.23"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define ENABLE_NLS 1
#define HAVE_GETTEXT 1
#define HAVE_DCGETTEXT 1
#define PACKAGE "xchm"
#define VERSION "1.23"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_LIBCHM 1
#define HAVE_XMLRPC_H 1

configure: exit 1
```

Anyway, I am not so good in C++. I simply want this program compiled...

### The question

What "Please install something" means in this context? What and where I have to copy and what console magic to type in order to install this library and to make `configure` happy?

Comment: heaving a header file doesn't mean the actual library is there. in many cases the header file's only present so an app can be compiled, yet still not be runable. so you might have xmlrpc.h, but not xmlrpc.so, which contains the actual executable code.

Comment: @MarcB - well, I have .a file as well...

Comment: Did you read `config.log` to find out what the error actually is?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - config.log is 38k and for me is a mess of strange words... But the same message as in the question appears somewhere at the end.

Comment: Read just before the message.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - It is too long. I pasted it in the question. But for me it means almost nothing... some defines and something failed...

Comment: *Almost* there. Post the error message that appears above that blurb.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - "fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory" - details, posted in the question...

Comment: That error shouldn't be showing up there. Sorry to do this, but more please.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - it is not a problem for me. I am simply afraid to not overload the question. Anyway, the whole .log in the question after 10 seconds.

Comment: Installing library usually means performing "make install", which copies it either somewhere into `/usr/lib` or into `/usr/local/lib`. However, if your system has package manager, use it instead of trying to build library manually. It is possible that your   program simply wants newer/older version or something.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - there is 30000char limit, so I was not able to paste the whole .log file and was forced to delete some part from the beginning.

Comment: @SigTerm - there is no package for this library and I can't make one. The library is almost not supported. Isn't it funny?

Comment: @johnfound: It isn't funny, because problems like that waste a lot of time. That's the reason why people hate(or start to hate) linux. Anyway, I checked sourceforge, and there's more than one c++ xmlrpc library (the first hit - xmlrpcpp - is a dead project from 10 years ago). Check "readme" file for the project you're trying to build and make sure you're compiling the right one. If you're trying to compile ancient software, and can't contact maintainer, basically you'll have to fix it yourself - figure out what is wrong, fix. I think that in your case libxmlrpc++ needs to be dynamically linked

Comment: @SigTerm - The big problem is that I need to compile xCHM viewer, but with support for some features that require XMLRPC++ library. The viewer itself is a popular program, distributed in all major Linux distributions, but always compiled without this library... Anyway, **this problem** is solved. The next one is coming. :)

Comment: @johnfound: "I need to compile xCHM viewer" If you only need a viewer, then kchmviewer should be able to view *.chm files, plus you should be able run sumatrapdf via wine.

Comment: @SigTerm, there is a reason I need exactly xCHM. Or you think I am idiot that can't search for the available CHM viewers?

Comment: @johnfound: you know, if you take every advise as insult to your intelligence, it'll become harder to get free help over time. "Or you think I am idiot" So far I had no reason to bother thinking about it, so I haven't thought about it. I have better thing to do than evaluating potential intelligence for every random stranger I "meet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
> ```

You need to install the `openssl-dev` package.

Comment: They goofed up the autotools scripts. They forgot to check for OpenSSL first.

Comment: Well, anyway... I hate C++... and Unix... the assembly is easier for debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately this is neither C++'s not Unix's fault; the blame lies directly on the shoulders of the project's developers.

Comment: Well I am not very sure... From my point of view, if the configure utility misses openssl, then it is weird to output error message about another library. I almost understand how this can happen, but it is probably because of the Unix philosophy about simple, ascii based tools that pipe tons of text from one CLI application to another and as a result no one knows how all this works. ;)

Comment: The check was coded for this library, but another prerequisite library wasn't checked for earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Most Linux distros have packages for popular software, I believe "libxmlrpc" is considered popular by most. So "install library" means starting up your package manager, searching for the library, and installing it. You might need to install the "devel" version of the package too.

If you get software from a tarball (.tar.gz, .tar.bz2, etc), usually it includes an **INSTALL** file with instructions on how to get it installed.

Comment: See the comments in the Sukhanov Niсkolay answer.